# How to pass variables with 2 2D Arrays in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing

I am having issues passing arrays to my methods it is getting an error of "cannot find symbol"but I am confused on how these 2D arrays should be passed in the method "how many" This program is supposed to prompt for 18 ints and placed into 2 2D arrays then return of they are equal or not. Am I supposed to place the array names in  `boolean equalOrNot = howmany(FirstArray, SecondArray);`
or what?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class n01092281
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

      int FirstArray [][] = new int[3][3];
      int SecondArray [][] = new int[3][3];

      System.out.print("Enter List1 and List2 (18 numbers): ");
      for (int row = 0; row < FirstArray.length; row++)
      {
          for(int column = 0; column < FirstArray[row].length; column++)
          {
              FirstArray[row][column] = input.nextInt();
          }
      }
      for (int row = 0; row < SecondArray.length; row++)
      {
          for(int column = 0; column < SecondArray[row].length; column++)
          {
              SecondArray[row][column] = input.nextInt();
          }
      }        
      boolean equalOrNot = howmany(FirstArray, SecondArray);   
         if (equalOrNot)
        {
            System.out.println("Two Arrays Are Equal");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Two Arrays Are Not equal");
        }  



   }   
   public class strict 
   { 
      public boolean howmany(int[][] FirstArray, int[][] SecondArray)
      {
         boolean equalOrNot = true;

        if(FirstArray.length == SecondArray.length)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < FirstArray.length; i++)
            {
                if(FirstArray[i] != SecondArray[i])
                {
                    equalOrNot = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            equalOrNot = false;
        }




      }   
     }

  }
```

Comment: Where is the method located? Where is the call to it? Are these the same to classes? If "no", why do you think you can call the method with a simple `howmany(...)`? `if(FirstArray[i] != SecondArray[i])` is also wrong

Comment: Yes they are in different classes. Am I not able to call items from other classes?

Comment: Are you able to call someone without entering a telephone number? You haven't specified from which class you call that method, thus that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: so howmany(FirstArray, SecondArray); should be strict.howmany(FirstArray, SecondArray); ?

Comment: [How to call a method in java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3713643)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few points that could help over the shared code :

1. Please follow better-naming conventions.
2. `public boolean howmany` does not have a return statement to actually `return` a boolean value, possibly add at the end of the method :

   ```
   return equalOrNot;
   ```
3. The comparison  should also be over the number of columns of the array and the condition should become somewhat like :

   ```
   if(FirstArray[i][j] != SecondArray[i][j])
   ```
4. You cannot call `howmany` method currently from a static context even considering `Strict` to be an inner class(with those inappropriately matched braces).

Comment: Thanks for the input, what would be the correct way to call it?

Comment: @JayDoe Create an instance of your class `strict` and use that to call the method.